# Can't connect in Forged Alliance Forever (FAF)

Tags: technical-issues, supreme-commander, forged-alliance-forever

I successfully installed FAF, and managed to set up an account. On two occassions I also managed to enter the game lobbies. However, in every other case, I just get presented with the "Connecting" screen. Here is what I have tried so far:

- Toggling Windows Firewall
- Toggling UPnP option
- Toggling router UPnP
- Toggling router Trigger Forwarding for UDP port 6112

Any ideas as to what else I could try?

Comment: Yes, ask in their support forum, the support is pretty good. A new proxy feature was added recently that sorted out lots of connection issues as well.

Answer (score 1):

sorry to only show up now (I see you asked your question 7 years ago :/ )

but the ICE network adapter for FAF finally dropped, like a month and a half ago.
https://github.com/FAForever/java-ice-adapter

https://www.faforever.com/2019/04/legacy-client-ice-release

it alone should obliterate any connectivity issues you had. Please, I'd be very curious to know if that's the case.

What ICE does is provide a sort of better proxy connection. The connection remains just as fast or faster but you no longer have such issues as FA.exe not knowing how to route between two different PCs in the world. anyone can connect with any one now.

You no longer need port forwarding which makes installation that much easier

And you can now play with several people connected under a submask of the same IP (LAN) it no longer makes connection fail.

You can also loose connection, get issued a new ip from your isp or heck change your source of internet altogether in the middle of a game, (say you were connected by ethernet but you unplug it mid-game and use your pone as a wifi hotspot using the data connection on your phone to continue, and that will work. you will be able to resume the game.

(you'll need to uninstall old client, got  to faf website, download and reinstall)

Comment: Maybe you can give the link and add some more info?

Comment: there you go :) !